# Visual Studio 2017 - Collapse all documentation sections

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-macros

I'm working with Visual Studio 2017 and I was wondering if there is a way to collapse all the **documentation sections only** ? 
There's a lot of them and most of the time I find that it's not useful to have them as the person who wrote the code.

I tried macros but it seems broke since VS2008.

**[The idea came from here](http://www.helixoft.com/blog/collapse-all-xml-comments-in-vb-net-or-c.html)**

Comment: It's a nice idea, but I haven't come across that.

Comment: @mrsundquist I've updated my question with a link where it provides a solution but only for VS08/10

Comment: I think macros were disabled in the recent versions of VS. I've used [VCMD](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SergeyVlasov.VisualCommander) to write macros for VS 2015 and VS 2017.